# Creating an async/await API wrapping a request/response protocol

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I have a request/response protocol that runs over TCP that I'd like to provide an async/await API for.  The protocol is STOMP, which is a fairly simple text-based protocol that runs over TCP or SSL.  In STOMP, the client sends one of six or so command frames and specifies a `receipt` ID in the header of the command.  The server will respond with either a `RECEIPT` or `ERROR` frame, with a `receipt-id` field, so the client can match the response with the original request.  The server can also send a `MESSAGE` frame at any time (STOMP is fundamentally a messaging protocol) which will not contain a `receipt-id`.

To allow multiple outstanding requests and handle any `MESSAGE` frames, the plan is to always have a `Socket.BeginReceive()` outstanding.  So what I was thinking is that the easiest implementation would be to create a waitable event (like a mutex), store that event in a table, send the command request with the `receipt` set to the index into the table, and block on the event.  When `socket.BeginReceive()` fires the function can get the `receipt-id` from the message, look up the event in the table, and signal it (and store some state, like success or error).  This will wake up the calling function, which can look at the result and return success or failure to the calling application.

Does this sound fundamentally correct?  I've used async/await APIs before but have never written my own.  If it's OK what kind of waitable event should I use?  A simple `Monitor.Wait()` will block but not in the way I want, correct?  If I wrap the whole thing in `Task.Run()` will that behave properly with `Monitor.Wait()`?  Or is there a new synchronization construct that I should be using instead?  I'm basically implementing `HttpClient.GetAsync()`, does anyone know how that works under the covers?

Comment: Try looking at WCF http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx very efficient!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpClient` is much simpler, because HTTP only has one response for each request. There's no such thing as an unsolicited server message in HTTP.

To properly set up a "stream" of events like this, it's best to use [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582.aspx) or [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609). Otherwise, you'd have to create an unbounded receive buffer and have repeated async ReceiveMessage calls.

So I'd recommend using a TPL Dataflow pipeline to create a source block of "messages", and then matching some up with requests (using `TaskCompletionSource` to notify the sender it's complete) and exposing the rest (`MESSAGE` frames) as a source block.

Internally, your processing pipeline would look like this:

- Repeated `BeginReceive` ->
- `TransformBlock` for message framing ->

  - `ActionBlock` to match response messages to requests.
  - `BufferBlock` for `MESSAGE` frames.

Comment: Big up for TPL DataFlow. Well suited to this kind of problem.